# Documents(.docx) with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I can't use python-docx library with pyinstaller.

Is there any library or way to handling .docx files by using pyinstaller?

Comment: Just for other who end up here: This Question includes a solution to use python-docx with PyInstaller by including the corresponding templates: [PyInstaller and python-docx module do not work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642322/pyinstaller-and-python-docx-module-do-not-work-together)