# How to fix PackageNotFoundError for exe files

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-docx

It gives me the error only after I have converted it to an exe, works fine as a .py file

I tried to find the file missing and replace it but it still didn't work.
The error I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "tkinter_init_.py", line 1705, in call
>
> File "CompilerGui.py", line 259, in
>
> done = ttk.Button(window, text="Compile", command=lambda:finish(texts,
>   window, search_folder))
>
> File "CompilerGui.py", line 210, in finish cb.the_main(q_list, values)
>
> File "CompilerBase.py", line 323, in the_main
>
> file_written = write_docx(values_dict, file_to_write)
>
> File "CompilerBase.py", line 100, in write_docx
>
> my_docx = docx.Document()
>
> File "site-packages\docx\api.py", line 25, in Document
>
> File "site-packages\docx\opc\package.py", line 128, in open
>
> File "site-packages\docx\opc\pkgreader.py", line 32, in from_file
>
> File "site-packages\docx\opc\phys_pkg.py", line 31, in new
>
> docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at
>   'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI92522\docx\templates\default.docx'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller and python-docx module do not work together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642322/pyinstaller-and-python-docx-module-do-not-work-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to the problem, it was looking for a folder that didn't exist. Here's how I fixed it : https://youtu.be/bB9RXak4eVY

Answer (score 0):

In your `.spec` file, I think you can add:

```
datas= [ ('C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\docx\\templates\\*', 'docx\\templates' ) ],
```

in the `Analysis` section, to add the missing file to your `exe`. This, of course, assumes that the missing `default.docx` is in the specified folder.

Comment: Thanks John Anderson but that didn't work, I tried it

Answer (score 0):

Another fairly simple fix would be to just copy the `default.docx` into your app directory, change `my_docx = docx.Document()` to `my_docx = docx.Document(docx='default.docx')`, and add `datas=[('default.docx', '.')]` to your `.spec` file.

Comment: Oh yeah ! And then save it as something else ! That would have been a good solution ! I'll keep that in mind next time .Thank you !