# Python-docx and Pyinstaller not working together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, python-docx

Good evening all, I've recently completed an app I was working on in python, and now that I am packaging it using Pyinstaller, but after packaging it, I tried to use the app for its purpose and generate some reports, however, it suddenly can't in the exe file but works in the text editor and is not showing any errors for some odd reason, I've tried [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642322/pyinstaller-and-python-docx-module-do-not-work-together) to no avail and I am now lost.

.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from os import path
site_packages = next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p)
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Newark\\newarkp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Newark'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(path.join(site_packages,"docx","templates"), 
"docx/templates")],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Newark',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , icon='C:\\Users\\Admin\\Newark\\logo_icon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\Admin\\Newark\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               name='Newark',
               upx=True,)
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I figured it out, some of my files got misplaced during the packaging so when I tried to use them, they were using another useless file and nothing was happening as a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone seeing this, some of my files got misplaced during the packaging so when I tried to use them, they were using another useless file and nothing was happening as a result.

Always check that your files are in the correct directories after packaging